# I want to duplicate all content into a new enabled language

Tags: nodes, i18n-l10n

I have 5000+ articles that so far were in one language; I want to make a new language available, but it would be very useful to at least create the content by copying the current one with images and texts, then just pasting my translations.

It saves me weeks of work for not having to recreate every node and uploading videos and images.

How can I loop through all nodes of a type in PHP, and to create its translation?
What I want to do is something similar to this pseudo-code:

```
for ($allnodes as $node) {
   $translated_node = create_node_in_language($node, $lang);
   copy_all_content_from_node($node, $transated_node);
}
```

I don't know how to use the drupal API to accomplish this, but I'm sure it is possible.

The one issue that can occur is the mandatory fields that have to be filled upon saving a new translation, and which needs to be copied from the original node.

Comment: It is possible to programmatically clone nodes, but I don't think it is possible to programmatically translate nodes.

Comment: since they disabled google translate api, it isn't posible to translate..but cloning will do, because it will save me some work

Comment: Have you tried [node clone](http://drupal.org/project/node_clone) ?